# How to create single page site in WordPress

Tags: wp-query, pages, frontpage

I have total 5 pages on my website, I want to display all pages as single page.

It is possible?

Example: http://yaremchuk.ru

Comment: Thank you to guide Me, I have improved my question please check it

Comment: Glad my answer works for you. Next time, try to post in the question your research upon a problem, and possibly the code you have written... This question is *acceptable*, but sure isn't the best question I've seen in this site. Of course, this comment is not a reproof, but a tip to help you on your next questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a child theme for your current theme. Read how to [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

After that create a file in your child theme named `front-page.php`. This is the first file WordPress will look for when you visit the home page of your site.

To understand why, read [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

In that file use:

```
<?php

get_header();

$all_pages = get_pages();
global $post;
echo '<div class="pages-container">';
foreach ( $all_pages as $post ) {
   setup_postdata($post);
   // improve the content, this is an example
   echo '<h2>' . the_title() . '</h2>';
   echo '<div class="page">' . the_content() . '</div>';
}
echo '</div>';
wp_reset_postdata();

get_footer();
```

The docs for function I've used are here:

- [get_pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages)
- [setup_postdata](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata)
- [wp_reset_postdata](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata)
- also [get_header](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header) and [get_footer](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_footer)